# (From Milne) If $L/F$ is an extension of ﬁelds of degree 2, then there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ such that $F$ is the ﬁxed ﬁeld of $\sigma$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group, separable-extension

This is an exercise in Milne's notes.
[image]

The answer is short, it says:

> (a) is false—could be inseparable. (b) is true—couldn’t be inseparable.

So may I please ask how does it related to separablity? What is the point here? May I please ask for some explicit argument with an explicit example? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inseparable extension of degree $2$ is $L=F(\sqrt a)$ in characteristic $2$. As $\sqrt a$ is the unique square root of $a$ then any $F$-automorphism fixes $\sqrt a$ and so is trivial on $F$.

The classic example is the rational function field $L=\Bbb F_2(t)$
and $F=\Bbb F_2(t^2)$.

A separable extension of degree $2$ in characteristic $2$ is
an Artin-Schreier extension $L=F(b)$ where $b^2+b\in F$.
The nontrivial automorphism takes $b$ to $b+1$.

I am sure you know all about degree $2$ extensions in characteristics
other than $2$.